# I have a file that gets staged automatically when I stage any other file - WHY

Tags: git

This is absolutely infuriating. I haven't gotten any work done all morning. When ever I stage a file 'foo/bar.coffee', another COMPLETELY UNCHANGED file 'foo/map.coffee' also stages itself. I try to reset the repository to HEAD, no files are staged. I stage *bar.coffee*, now two files are staged. And the file *map.coffee* **isn't even modified**. In the diff (after it is staged) it shows every line of the file with a "-" in front of it, as if I had staged it for deletion.

This is how the diff comments at the top of *map.coffee* looks like after it has been staged:

```
diff --git a/src/controllers/map.coffee b/src/controllers/map.coffee
deleted file mode 100755
index e4d5d3b..0000000
--- a/src/controllers/map.coffee
+++ /dev/null
```

I have tried checking out a fresh *map.coffee* with no success, it keeps staging itself for deletion whenever I stage a file. Why is this?

Comment: can you show us a paste of the terminal session, including the commands you're using?

Comment: Have you tried cloning your repository again, maybe your .git folder is broken.

Comment: @Gareth http://pastebin.com/FaJZhBVM

Comment: @Shahbaz No I don't use any hooks, never have

Comment: @Intrepidd No I haven't tried that. I sort of assume the git folder is broken, but I haven't touched it and I won't accept that as a solution just like that. I want to figure out what's wrong and why, plus how to fix it short of just re-cloning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reset or checkout helped, so I ended up checking out the remote develop branch into a new folder, then merging the new folder with the old one (except the .git folders.) All the changes in the working directory since the last push ended up as unstaged changes which I just committed piece by piece.

I'm pretty sure it was the Git GUI's "archive compression" that caused this issue to begin with, since this all started the day I mistakenly clicked "yes" instead of "no".